# Android: Is it possible to detect consecutive forward and backward motion on Android Accelerometer?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I'm making an app that requires me to detect walking. I'm able to detect it.
I simply use deltaZ & deltaY values for accelerometer and some other parameters.

However a user is able to fake walking easily by simple moving it up and down and forward and backward.

So to prevent that, I guess if I can detect consecutive backward and forward motion, I can find that it was a fake step.

I tried reading the raw accelerometer values... However it didnt help much.
Anyone with any ideas on this?

PS: I have tried the pedometer apps and the github code. They detect steps well. But I can easily fake them by shaking the phone

Answer (score 0):

You can use GPS to detect their location, and if they are not changing location enough over time, you can invalidate their walking.

Comment: the movement would probably be 5-10 steps... so I guess i cant use GPS to detect such a small variation

Comment: You would especially have trouble if they were pulling their GPS from wifi.  I see your problem.  Conceptually, anything you do with your acceleromater can be faked.  You can only make it more difficult to fake, which will likely, in turn, make it less likely to read the data you want and be forgiving to a multitude of users.  You really need to see if their location has actually changed, and the only way I can think of doing that is with GPS.  Tough problem.